# What is the best way to override an existing shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh, ping

**If one were to have a need to do modify an existing shell command (built-in or otherwise), what is the best way to go about this?**

Let me state that I understand there are a number of potential risks involved in attempting a procedure such as this, but that is the very reason I ask this question.

I would like to create a shell function (called `ping`) to use in place of the common [ping](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/ping/) command. For the sake of this topic, let's say that it should at the very least be compatible in both [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) shell environments.

Specifically, I would like to allow for `ping` to accept full URLs in the hostname (with protocol, trailing slash/pathname, query parameters, etc). The string manipulation is not what is stumping me, but rather how to properly execute the original `ping` executable without calling the function something other than `ping`.

***For example***, the following two commands should yield the same result:

```
# EXAMPLE 2 (What `ping` will accept)
ping who.is

# EXAMPLE 1 (What I would like to be able to do with `ping`)
ping https://who.is/my/ping/?example=this
```

Comment: Your script is run with its own interpreter, not with the interpreter the user is running. That is to say, if you use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, your script is run with bash, even if the user is using zsh/ksh/fish/whatever; so nothing at all changes based on the interpreter in use (*unless* you're trying to override a builtin, but that's a different, shell-specific case and you should ask a separate and distinct question about it).

Comment: ...that said, it sounds like you're asking how to *shadow an existing command*, not how to "modify an existing script" as in the original title. (`ping` isn't a script at all on most platforms -- it's typically a compiled executable written in C).

Comment: ...that said, `ping https://who.is/my/ping/?example=this` isn't generally reliable with most shells -- if the user has `failglob` turned on, for example, the command would fail before the script is even started, or if they have `nullglob` turned on it would be passed no arguments at all. Your user needs to provide quoting for a command with glob characters to be started correctly: `ping 'https://who.is/my/ping/?example=this'`, in this case.

Comment: Hi Charles. I'm talking about a bash or zsh function, not an executable script (e.g. `function ping() { /bin/ping $1 }`. Also, I understand the quoting would be necessary for a string with glob characters, but let's just simplify it to `ping 'https://who.is/'`

Comment: Just `ping() {`, not `function ping() {`, for best portability. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: ...and if you want to be portable, you **should** use an external script run by its own interpreter. Otherwise you need to deal with how your different shell languages do built-in regexes.

Comment: The POSIX shell [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) command (utility in POSIX-speak) is designed to run the real command — so you could/should use `command ping …` to run the real command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to address [@blizzrdof77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313496/blizzrdof77)'s [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915121/what-is-the-best-way-to-override-an-existing-shell-command/54095107#question%22%20title=%22Original%20Question) (*paraphrased below*):

> "I would like to create a shell function (*called* **'**`ping`') to use in place of the common `ping` command." <sup>[[ℹ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915121/what-is-the-best-way-to-override-an-existing-shell-command/54095107#question%22%20title=%22Original%20Question)</sup>

---

This drop-in portable shell *function* <sup>[[ℹ]](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05)</sup> works well on *Mac* & *Linux* in [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell),[`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)),[`sh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), and all [POSIX-compliant shells](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-posix-shell/).

```sh
# ---------------------------------------------------------
#  Better `ping` support for various URL formats/protocols
#
#  @param $1 - hostname
#  EXAMPLE USAGE: `ping http://google.com/`
# ---------------------------------------------------------

ping() {
    local pingdomain="$1"
    shopt -s nocasematch # allow lowercase
    pingdomain=${pingdomain/#*:\/\/} # strip protocol
    pingdomain=${pingdomain/#*:*@/} # strip leading 'user:pass@'
    pingdomain=$(echo "${pingdomain//"?"//}") # remove '?'
    pingdomain="$(echo "$pingdomain" | cut -d/ -f 1)" # clear last '/'
    command ping $pingdomain
}
```

Comment: I might strip out the check for "$1" to slim it down a bit, but this works great. Thank you!

Comment: This code is modifying the variable `DOMAIN` even after the function exits. Better to declare your locals so you don't pollute global namespace, and also to stick to [lowercase names (which are reserved for application use)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) so one can't overwrite a meaningful environment variable by mistake.

Comment: And `Please` isn't a command. Maybe you want `echo "Please provide a hostname, domain, URL, or IP address." >&2; return 1` in the error case?

Comment: Note also that `function` comes from the legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {`, whereas `()` in function declarations comes from the Bourne and POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {`. Combining the `function` and the `()` to `function funcname() {` gives you a hybrid that works neither in legacy ksh *or* in baseline POSIX.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thanks for the suggestions! I went ahead and removed the check for an argument altogether, as it prevents the default behavior of the built-in `ping` command.  I also updated the function to use local variable names.

Answer (score 4):

A shim might look like the following (if your real `ping` is in `/usr/bin`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
uri_re='^[[:alnum:]]+://([^/]+)/'

if [[ $1 =~ $uri_re ]]; then
  exec /usr/bin/ping "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${@:2}"
else
  exec /usr/bin/ping "$@"
fi
```

Put it somewhere like `/opt/overrides/bin`, and put that earlier in the PATH than `/usr/bin` (so `PATH=/opt/overrides/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` or such).

---

Or, for a portable function that will work on all POSIX-compliant shells (and zsh as well, even though it doesn't try to be one):

```
ping() {
  local _ping_addr >/dev/null 2>&1 ||: "ignore failure on shells that don't support local"
  case $1 in
    *://*/)
      _ping_addr=${1#*://}
      _ping_addr=${_ping_addr%%/*}
      shift
      command ping "$_ping_addr" "$@"
      ;;
    *)
      command ping "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```